# Android: Spinner populated by Volley request cannot return selected item

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-volley, android-spinner

I am attempting to populate a spinner with the results of a Volley POST request and having got this functionality working. The spinner populates with the results found in the online Database. However, although the items display within the spinner whenever it is opened, the chosen item cannot be accessed.

An error message is returned:

```
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

The method call above the spinner inputs all of the volley responses into an array of times available. Here is the code from my onCreateView (The spinner is in a fragment):

```
//method call to send Volley request for available date and time and add to arraylist
        populateAvailSlots(user_id);
        // you can use this array to populate your spinner
        spWhenChoice = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spWhenChoice);
        ArrayAdapter<String> whenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, availSlots.getAList());
        whenAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spWhenChoice.setAdapter(whenAdapter);
        spWhenChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                       int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                String timeSelected =  spWhenChoice.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                System.out.println(timeSelected);
                spinBundle.putString("timeSelected", timeSelected);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                //empty string
            }
        });
```

Once the item has been selected I am attempting to store it's text and pass it through the fragment on buttonclick:

```
 btnStudBook = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStudBook);
        btnStudBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (spinBundle.isEmpty()) {
                    //inform the user that they need to select from spinner
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select a time",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //create an object of the class to navigate to
                    StudAppointInput fragment = new StudAppointInput();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.studBaseLayout, fragment);
                    //add back button functionality
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    fragment.setArguments(spinBundle);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Check if [this](http://www.laurivan.com/attempted-to-finish-an-input-event/) is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately it doesn't give me any clear answers. It does imply that my code needs a complete restructure though, which I'll attempt now.

Comment: Let's hope that error will resolve after refactoring. Just update on that if you have time.